# How can I display the text in the text field in the text area when I clicked the button?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

This is what I have tried so far:

```
{
    TextField tf;
    JTextArea ta; 

    public TextListener()
    {
        gui();
    }

    public void gui()
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        tf = new JTextField("",20);
        ta = new JTextArea("",20,20);
        JButton b = new JButton("SHOW"); 

        f.add(p);
        p.add(tf);
        p.add(b);
        p.add(ta);

        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setSize(400,200);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {
        String name = tf.getText();
        ta.append(name);
    }

    public static void main(String[] arg)
    {
        new TextListner();

    }
```

Comment: Don't post an image of your code. Post the actual code in the form of an [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Text Areas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html) for a working example.

The example in the tutorial adds an `ActionListener` to the text field. So you can just use the "Enter" key to add the text to the text area.

However you can simply modify the code to use a JButton and add the ActionListener to the button as well as the text field.